# Assign ActionLink to jQuery button in MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How do I assign ActionLink to a jQuery button in asp.net MVC page.

```
<button id="Button1">Click</button>

<%: Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")%>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $("#Button1").button().click(function () {
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean give the button the same src as the ActionLink?

Comment: On click on jQuery button I want to load view 'About'. I am not sure if I need Html.ActionLink there.

Comment: yes you don't need that `ActionLink`, check my answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your comments, you just want to go to the About action in the Home controller on button click, you can do the following and remove the `ActionLink`:

```
$(function () {
    $("#Button1").click(function () {
        location.href = '<%= Url.Action("About", "Home") %>';
    });
});
```

Comment: I am getting error CS1002: ; expected on location.href = '<% Url.Action("About", "Home") %>';

Comment: Try adding a ; after Url.Action

Comment: Thanks no error now, but nothing happens after I click the button.
I tried to view the source, it shows

            $("#Button1").button().click(function () {
                window.location.href = '';
            });

Comment: @CoolArchTek ah it turns out you don't need the semi colon, you just need the `=` after `<%`, check my new edit I tested and it works :) I'm used to RAZOR syntax hehe :)

Comment: No problems, glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Give the anchor an `id`:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", null, new { id = "Button1"})%>
```

Using this [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124):

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes // <==============
)
```

Comment: Do I need to have anchor (Html.ActionLink(....) )? Is it possible to write something in jQuery button javascript to call the target page?

Comment: The anchor is appearing as normal link. I wanted to use jQuery UI controls (for better UI with themes etc).

Comment: @CoolArchTek. Then add the element or what ever you want an `onclick` event: `$('#elementId').click(function(){ /* What you want here... */})` Note that you should ask one question in a thread...

Answer (score 0):

The [button](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/) method of jQuery works for a tag too, try this:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", null, new { id="Button1" })%>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $("#Button1").button().click(function () {
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you meant jquery UI not jquery.

Comment: Dude, he is using jQuery UI, but Ok, you think it's wrong like you said!

Comment: my mistake, I edited the question.  Your answer was a bit unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", new { @class = "yourclass" })%>
```

You can try attaching a class to the actionlink and you can select it with query.  If you want to use a class.

Comment: It's not the right overload... :(. You gave that parameters as the `routeValues`...

Comment: That should still work.  I just tried it.. unless I'm wrong since I'm using razor :O

Comment: Adding routesValue will no compile asp.net mvc.